# Mythbuntu initial setup cannt connect to server

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I'm really new to linux, and I just installed mythbuntu to a standalone pc, it's all installed ok and I've logged on, and started the setup but I'm having issues. I select language ok, the next screen is database setup, select next but it says can't connect to server and I just loop back.

I've done some googling and checked the mysql database password and that is correct, I've also checked that my username belongs to myth tv and it does.

Can anyone help? I've tried reinstalling but it doesn't change.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a quick start guide that may be useful. You can add comments directly to it if any part of it is confusing or you have any questions and I'll try to fix it.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/19knOlqz8cV5_8VQ1tCvEd8tjEk6U50KsSOJCROR60o4/edit?usp=sharing